Random effects in GAMs with mgcv vs random effects in LMMs with lme4
This blog post considers an example where GAMs from the mgcv package are used to model random effects:
m1_gam <- gam(response ~ treatment:transf_time +
                   s(subject, bs = 're') +
                   s(subject, transf_time, bs = 're'),
               data = rats, method = 'REML')

Estimated coefficients:
             (Intercept) treatmentControl:transf_time 
               68.607385                     6.871130 
treatmentLow:transf_time    treatmentHigh:transf_time 
                7.506897                     7.313859 

The same can be achieved using LMMs from the lme4 package:
m1_lmer <- lmer(response ~ treatment:transf_time +
                    (1 | subject) + (0 + transf_time | subject),
                data = rats)

Estimated coefficients:
             (Intercept) treatmentControl:transf_time 
               68.607386                     6.871128 
treatmentLow:transf_time    treatmentHigh:transf_time 
                7.506897                     7.313854

The coefficients are more or less numerically equal. I understand that smoothing and random effects are related  (see for example this blog post for more details). So I thought that setting the smoother to bs = 're' always coincide with the results of a mixed model.
While working on my current project, I noticed significant discrepancies between the estimates obtained from different models.  I'm interested in understanding the broader reasons for these variations.  Specifically, could you outline the general scenarios where model choice can lead to differing results? Note that I want to focus on the underlying principles rather than troubleshooting my specific dataset.
Edit:
GAM
Formula:
    gam(response ~ x * z + s(id, bs = 're'), data = dat, method = 'REML')
    

Results:

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ x * z + s(id, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.79296    0.19227   9.325  < 2e-16 ***
xB           0.52331    0.16352   3.200  0.00155 ** 
xC           0.54522    0.23239   2.346  0.01976 *  
xD           0.72385    0.27530   2.629  0.00909 ** 
xE           0.08863    0.19363   0.458  0.64755    
zB          -0.29782    0.27771  -1.072  0.28459    
zC          -0.22697    0.27395  -0.829  0.40818    
xB:zB        0.21956    0.33158   0.662  0.50849    
xC:zB        0.20965    0.34387   0.610  0.54264    
xD:zB        0.00000    0.00000     NaN      NaN    
xE:zB       -0.09368    0.31749  -0.295  0.76820    
xB:zC       -0.78537    0.32578  -2.411  0.01665 *  
xC:zC        0.00000    0.00000     NaN      NaN    
xD:zC        0.00000    0.00000     NaN      NaN    
xE:zC       -0.32421    0.32542  -0.996  0.32009    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df     F p-value  
s(id) 0.8024      1 0.812  0.0245 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 13/16
R-sq.(adj) =  0.291   Deviance explained = 32.3%
-REML = 231.83  Scale est. = 0.33354   n = 259

Output of gam.vcomp:
Standard deviations and 0.95 confidence intervals:

           std.dev        lower        upper
s(id) 0.0001428587 2.539161e-05 0.0008037544
scale 0.5810776345 5.316464e-01 0.6351048744

Rank: 2/2

LMM
Formula:
lmer(response ~ x * z + (1|id), data = dat)

Results:
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: y ~ x * z + (1 | id)
   Data: A

REML criterion at convergence: 435.6

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.73598 -0.30450  0.09023  0.42022  1.67375 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.2318   0.4814  
 Residual             0.1342   0.3663  
Number of obs: 259, groups:  id, 159

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  1.51796    0.12603  12.044
xB           0.56720    0.11964   4.741
xC           0.66009    0.18674   3.535
xD           0.79883    0.22189   3.600
xE           0.08228    0.16420   0.501
zB          -0.41157    0.22818  -1.804
zC          -0.57851    0.16894  -3.424
xB:zB        0.38644    0.23242   1.663
xC:zB        0.29585    0.27484   1.076
xE:zB        0.11743    0.24903   0.472
xB:zC       -0.18383    0.20197  -0.910
xC:zC        0.05760    0.26180   0.220

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr) xB     xC     xD     xE     zB     zC     xB:zB  xC:zB  xE:zB  xB:zC 
xB    -0.729                                                                      
xC    -0.551  0.576                                                               
xD     0.000  0.000  0.000                                                        
xE    -0.645  0.578  0.432  0.000                                                 
zB    -0.552  0.403  0.304 -0.679  0.356                                          
zC    -0.119 -0.017 -0.009  0.000 -0.491  0.066                                   
xB:zB  0.375 -0.515 -0.297  0.538 -0.297 -0.722  0.009                            
xC:zB  0.374 -0.391 -0.679  0.561 -0.294 -0.750  0.006  0.621                     
xE:zB  0.425 -0.381 -0.285  0.585 -0.659 -0.792  0.323  0.664  0.664              
xB:zC -0.093 -0.123  0.010  0.000  0.471  0.051 -0.601  0.063 -0.007 -0.310       
xC:zC -0.012 -0.049 -0.442  0.000  0.319  0.006 -0.434  0.025  0.300 -0.210  0.353
fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 3 columns / coefficients


It may be helpful to include information about the models you recently fit in order to get some information about how it may differ between the two functions.

Thanks for your reply. I added the model formulas.

@SydAmerikaner the addition isn't really very helpful. You claim that the models produce difference estimates but you don't show the estimates themselves (show the model summary() outputs for example. The two functions gam() and lmer() are using very different estimation algorithms; so they don't always have to coincide if there is something about your data that might be causing problems for one or both of the fitting functions. Please show the output from summary(), plus the output from gam.vcomp() for the gam() model.

You are right, I should have added the results in the first place. I thought it may distract from what I am mainly interested in: why do the results differ (not only in my case but in general). I know that different algorithms are implemented. However, after reading your blog post, I thought that I can always expect very similar estimates.

The key is, I think, these two bits of information:

fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 3 columns / coefficients

from the lmer() model and

Rank: 13/16

from the gam() model.
I suspect this rank deficiency is causing differences in the estimated fixed effects due to difference in the details of the two algorithms. lmer() straight up dropped the aliased terms from the model matrix, while gam() continued with the rank deficient columns still there. I suspect this lead to differences in the estimated fixed effects which leads to the observed differences in the "estimates" of the random effects.
Try dropping the interaction term and refit both models and you should find the estimates to be much closer.
Excluding the rank deficiency issue, the mixed effects and GAM/penalized spline representations of your models are mathematically equivalent. If your data is well behaved, the two approaches (with their different algorithms) will typically converge to effectively the same estimated fixed effects and "estimated" random effects (it's unlikely the estimates will be exactly the same, but differences should be trivial in most cases). But this doesn't have to hold in practice despite the mathematical equivalence.

Thanks for your reply. If I remove the interaction effect I get indeed a full-rank matrix. So I suppose the data is well-behaved then? Or what else could be further examples for non-well haved data? (this is essentially my question). Because there are still quite big differences in magnitude of the estimated coefficients. For example, the intercept estimated using GAM is 1.71322, while the one estimated by LMER is 1.45371.
